# derivative of parameter integral in $\mathbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be continuous and let $g(x):=xf(x)$ be absolutely integrable. Then $\widehat f'=-i\widehat g$.

I know this would be true if I can differentiate in the integral of $\widehat f(w)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp(-iwx)dx$.

But when can I do that?

I know in $\mathbb R$ that $g'(y)=\int_a^b\frac d{dy}f(x,y)dx$ holds if $f$ is continuously partial differentiable.

But now my fourier transform is in $\mathbb C$. So are conditions the same? And why?

Comment: Do you mean $\widehat{(\operatorname{f}')}$ or $(\widehat{\operatorname{f}})'$?

Comment: @FlybyNight I mean $(\widehat f)'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier transformation is defined on real function - it's essential. The condition of partial derivative under the integral is uniformal convergence. So, you should show, that $\int\limits^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{\left|xf(x)e^{-iwx}\right|dx}$ converges uniformly. That's easy.